# Alternatives to synrchonous AJAX calls for absolute needed files?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backbone.js

I'm currently building a backbone app where I absolutely need some files before proceeding with certain tasks.

For Example:

1. the template files for rendering a view
2. a `language.json` file that holds the copy for the whole app

Now what I want to avoid is the callback hell that brings me to. Like I could never use `this.template(data)` because I always have to check a deferred object / promise if that template is already loaded.

```
getTemplate: function(path) {

    return $.get('/templates/'+path).then(function(src) {

        // is the copy already available?
        return App.Deferreds.copy.then(function(copy) {

            // insert copy into this html string
            src = App.Models.Copy.insertCopy(src, copy);

            // return a handlebars tempate with copy pre-filled
            return Handlebars.compile(src);

        });


    });

}
```

So I thought I'd make the AJAX requests for those files synchronous and return the files content instead of a promise.

```
getTemplate: function(path) {

    var template;

    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: '/templates/'+path,
        async: false,
        success: function(src) {

            // insert copy into this html string
            src = App.Models.Copy.insertCopy(src, copy);

            template = Handlebars.compile(src);
        }
    });

    return template;

}
```

Now chrome is telling me `synchronous xmlhttprequest on the main thread is deprecated`. And after researching it it is indeed removed from the specs (or will be).

Now what's my alternative here?
How do I load absolutely needed files via JavaScript into a web-app?

It seems odd to use AJAX in the first place when I ALWAYS have to wait for those files.

Comment: Use Plain Javascript AJAX with synchronous.

Comment: the json is loaded after the app determined / the user chose the language to load. Think 52 languages - of course I only want to load the necessary one.
I don't precombile the templates because I have to recompile them anyways at some point or the other (e.g. language switch, model change).

Comment: Is there a reason not to use a module loader such as requireJS or browserify?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are trying to implement a poor man's dependancy management system.
You should consider using an existing one such as [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) or [Browserify](http://browserify.org/)

Comment: great idea - I'll have a look and accept your answer when it solves my problem